# IntelliJ red blocking mark before file name

Tags: svn, maven, intellij-idea

I checked out from SVN in IntelliJ and have a folder including three files having the red mark before file name. I do not know why it happened and I can not create new class in that folder. I tried mvn clean install, after building success, in 10 scecond, the mark disappeared, then it came back. HelP!

Thank you so much! Already wasting one day on this.

Comment: What if you hover above the red marks, does it display some more information? And if you open the `Event Log` (down in the right corner) you may see some more info too.

Comment: Can you post a screen capture?

Comment: Post a screenshot. Most probably, these files are not in source code folder (at least, Idea thinks so).